# Play audio in HTML5 game for mobile phone with collision

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-audio

What is the best way for Playing audio in HTML5 game for mobile phone with collision.
I trying to use audio tag in HTML5, but there are a delay in sound when the collision repeated quickly !!!!!
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Once I've been playing around with HTML 5 and GameDevelopment - trying things out and so on. For Sound I used Soundmanager, take a look here: [Click Here](http://www.html5place.com/2011/01/how-to-use-audio-with-html5-games/) , maybe this can help you. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Dose soundManager will be useful with mobile phones which dose NOT support flash ?

Comment: No, SoundManager 2 is the result of Javascript talking to a hidden Flash movie. The Flash layer is not something you have to work with directly, but it is the component which makes audio control possible behind the scenes.

Comment: If that is important for you, you better should state your question more precisely :)

Answer (score 0):

sound playing is limited to 1 sound at time on iPhone and have a big latency,
latency is probably the same on Android.

then unfortunately, it's actually not possible to use <audio> on game for collision sound. (you can use it for background music).